# What does the commander mean when he says there is a new HVT?

Tags: battlefield-4

When playing in online, occasionally I hear over ther speakers that a new HVT has been established (or some version of that statement).    Here are my presumptions:

HVT = High Value Target, assigned by our commander, & I will earn more XP if I find and kill the HVT.

Is this correct?  If so, do they show up on my radar & how much extra XP do you earn?

Comment: Is it HTV or HVT (as per your assumption of High Value Target)?

Comment: Sorry about the confusion, I edited it.  Thank you.

Comment: Man I messed that up everywhere.  Need more coffee...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> High Value Target is a default commander resource featured in
>   Battlefield 4. It reveals the location of an enemy to the entire team
>   for 45 seconds, becoming available once that enemy has reached a six
>   or more kill streak. Bonuses are awarded to players who eliminate
>   HVTs, and to HVTs themselves for continuing their kill streaks.

Ref: http://battlefield.wikia.com/wiki/High_Value_Target_(Commander_Resource)

Comment: Oh Nice!  Do you know about how much the bonuses are? And when revealed, do they look different on the mini map?

Comment: They have  a square with a downside triangle on them instead of the dorito

Comment: Do you know the bonus amount for killing a HVT?

Comment: @ZeroStack I think the value changes based on their kill streak, ie its a base value for the 6 kills that increases by a small amount for each additional kill, though I am unsure on that